# Facebook Sharer URL Thumbnail Rules

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, random, meta-tags

Does anyone know the exact rules of the Facebook sharer thumbnail?

From my understanding, what it is supposed to do, is look at the `<head>` and find the `<meta type="of:image">` and have that as the default thumbnail, but what it should also do, is crawl the webpage, find all the images on it, and have it alternative thumbnail options.

Am I completely wrong here?

Take a look at this site for example, http://a-d-c.net 
When on the Homepage, click on the Share link (select Facebook one) on the bottom nav, I can only see 3 thumbnail options, even though there are plenty of other images on the page.

Can anyone explain how Facebook decide which images are 'allowed' to be used as the thumbnail?

Kind Regards

Comment: No, AFAIK FB only looks for images in the page code itself if there is no `og:image` meta element provided.

Comment: In the example website above, there is no `og:image` meta

Comment: I think FB displays only a maximum of three images to choose from nowadays. Even if you specify more with multiple `og:image` tags, they will only take the first three. A matter of user experience, I guess – who want’s to flip to two dozen images to pick one when sharing a link?